Does the Ukrainian treatment of a Russian deserter differ from a Russian combatant that surrenders?
I am curious about the fate of Russian deserters in Ukraine. If you desert the Russian military and surrender yourself in Ukraine as a Russian, are you granted any status in Ukraine? Are you subject to draft for Ukraine?
I would assume the treatment is different. I would assume you're incentiveized to lay down arms more before you exhaust the chance of a victory in combat. What treatment is given to those that want not to participate in the Russian war effort? I prefer laws cited that protect or incentivize deserting.

By deserter you mean someone who served in the armed forces and then decides not to fight any more, rather than someone who refuses military service entirely? Also, I'd guess treatment would be different depending on whether a Russian soldier surrenders on the battlefield or tries to enter Ukraine as a refugee/conscientious objector.

That is exactly the distinction I'm making @StackExchangeSupportsIsrael if I was Ukraine.

Why are people voting to close this?

Because, while parts of this question may be on-topic for Law Stack Exchange, it is almost certainly off-topic for Politics.

@alamar If it's off-topic, people should vote to close or flag as off-topic; that's not what down-votes are for.

@gerrit Who said I did? Nevertheless, I can't even mark it for closure; it says I un-marked it previously though I can't remember doing that.

This Q is a bit confusing - why would a deserter (someone who no longer wishes to fight in a war) run away to Ukraine if they will again be drafted to Ukrainian Army? If somebody is ready to fight for the other side, than they are not deserters but defectors.

@sfxedit I think OP might ask whether deserters would be subject to be drafted involuntarily into the Ukrainian armed forces, which I suppose might happen to Ukrainian rebels but surely not to Russian soldiers (who drafts foreigners?); the question becomes complicated if Donbass residents have taken Russian citizenship but Ukraine refuses to recognise this and still considers them Ukrainian.

@sfxedit I didn't say they were "ready to fight" I said they were drafted, which doesn't just mean exclusively on the front lines. It means forced to serve in the war effort for Ukraine. And it could happen for lots of reasons, (a) absolute desperation on the part of Ukraine, (b) a lower risk of death and bodily harm, (c) moral alignment with Ukraine. Fascists have a historical precedent for doing this to POWs look up "Osttruppen".

A significant difference is that the Russians keep them dispersed in various prisons of the country. The Ukrainians have built a camp for them, in the western side of the country.
There were many prisoner exchanges and the liberated prisoners talk. There are no reports of systematic violation of PoW rights on any side.
Sources:

this source says interviews of ukrainian prisoners in Russia. Not trustable source, obviously only those can appear here who say what the Russians want from them. It can be a partial information source in matters not important for the Russian war PR.
This guy became crippled for life while he fought under the influence of battle drugs in Mariupol. He is also considered a hero in Ukraine. Obviously he will replicate the Ukrainian version of the story.


I think you have misunderstood the question. The question is whether there's a difference between how Ukraine treats Russian who desert and are captured by Ukraine, versus how Ukraine treats Russian who are captured while fighting.
